# How to bind controls to different source from a datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, windows-8.1

I have a simple design with several hubsections into which I want to display a ListBox inside a Grid. The ListBox itself will contain two elements : a TextBlock and a TextBox.
The TextBlock in each HubSection will display the same property, so the data binding is quite easy. However, the TextBox should display a different property in each separate HubSection. I am lost and do not even have a clue on how I should proceed.
Here is my XAML code :

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BaseGridTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock                         
                       Text="{Binding PlayerName}"
                       FontSize="28"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding OtherProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Background="Lavender" FontSize="28"
                         Grid.Column="2">                                           
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>                   
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then in my HubSections, I want to use the above template to display data, like such:

```
       <HubSection Width="350" x:Uid="Test" Header="Test">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="TestListBox"  Grid.Column="1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BaseGridTemplate}" 
                         >    
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

In my UI, both properties (PlayerName and OtherProperty) are displayed correctly. But what I would like to do is to bind to a different property for the TextBox (i.e. different from OtherProperty).
I really have no clue on how I should proceed, or if it even is possible.

I thought I could to something like defining my TextBox in the Resources section like such :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

And then Hope I could add something in the HubSection part ?

Comment: Google datacontext. You can bind the datacontext to an object which has the values you need and then using the binding of the TextBox to a member of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a way of knowing when you have to use your different properties I think the best way for you to do this is to use a template selector and have different kind of templates based on what you want to display. 
Another alternative would be to use a value converter for TextBox and use the binding you suggested:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}">
```

These are just some ideas to get you started, another important thing to know is if are you trying to use a different property on the same object?

Comment: Thaks for trying to help. I'll check your suggestion as soon as possible. Maybe I should give some precision on the properties I want to bind to. They are all from the same class Players.cs, which contains 8 properties (such as Players.playerName; Players.playerScore1; Players.playerScore2; etc...). The difficulty is that I have to bind to the same Players.playerName property in each section but then to a different property in the TextBox (so a simple datacontext does not work)